# Relation between ranks of submatrices of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

[image]

If $\text{rank}(S(i-1,j-1))=\text{rank}(S(i,j-1))=\text{rank}(S(i-1,j))$
then there is  a unique value for $s_{ij}$
such that $\text{rank}(S(i,j))=\text{rank}(S(i-1,j-1))$, I want to know why does a unique value $s_{ij}$ exist?

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts in this and future posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The answer is too easy, but it seems they closed your question so I answer it here. By assuming '9', all s_k,j (k from 1 to i-1) is a linear combination of other columns and same but maybe different linear combination for s_i,k, now for the matrix S(i,j) you only don't know value of one entry which is S_i,j, S_i,j should satisfy the two linear relations using entries added in steps S(i-1,j) and S(i,j-1), obviously you can have at most one possible values conditioning to have a same results starting from linear relation of row or column, which is true..

Comment: In fact you only need to write the two computations for s_i,j and then using association of multiplication and distribution of multiplication on summation. It is easy to write it. ^_^

Comment: @mlo105 and others, I think toress needed at least an example to see the  reason of that sentence not closing his question, and his question is not missing anything, he is saying that he is not able to figure out reason of that implication.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles What we can see, the question has been asked is very clear. he is saying that he can not understand that part.